# How to extract number of observations for each year

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column of year and quantity. Below is a sample data:

```
year <- c(1985, 1985, 1983, 1985, 1983)
quantity <- c(2,1,4,6,1)
mydata <- data.frame(year, quantity)
```

I want to extract a number of observations for each year. I have used the following code for a specific observation and it works fine. However in my original dataset I have 50 different years and I need something that works better than repeating this for every year:

```
newdata <- subset(mydata, year == 1985, select=c(quantity)) 
str(newdata)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
table(mydata$year)
```

---

Or with `count`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
    count(year)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below another possible solution:

With `useNA = 'always'` you could detect possible `NA` values.

```
table(mydata$year, useNA = 'always')
```